# ServiceStack WebApi File Download From Another Service (Pass-Through)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, servicestack

Summary: I have an application service/API and a reporting service/API; mutually exclusive of each other (on different servers/environments; app service does not have access to reporting service file system). My front-end app calls the app service to build a report. The app service passes the BLL data that the report needs to the reporting service, which then builds the report and sends it back as an API. The app service then needs to pass along that PDF file and have it download from the browser.

The trouble I am having is the pass-through and getting the app service to download the file that the reporting service creats. The reporting service is confirmed successfully building the report. If I call in to the reporting service directly, I get the pdf download. However, when I call in through the app service, my response is a bunch of jumbled mess instead of being a file download.

Both services use ServiceStack on WebAPI, c# 6.

Here is a snippet of the response text:

```
%PDF-1.2 
%âãÏÓ 
1 0 obj 
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 2 0 R 
/PageMode /UseNone 
/ViewerPreferences << 
/FitWindow true 
/PageLayout /SinglePage 
/NonFullScreenPageMode /UseNone 
>> 
>> 
endobj 
5 0 obj 
<< 
/Length 5964 
/Filter [ /FlateDecode ] 
>> 
stream
xµ]ÛrÜF}çWTÄ¼4#D³î½IdÆthDywg­  DBT¯ÝÝÔüÇ~ðÃÄüÀf]d±q)zl;,<@¢pêdVV¢X¢ßPE(ü{Bãq\ÞÑðÃíu:xóí2øÿ£Ö&oë£ÿ>j8yuÄ)ùÇr0-%aÔYJ¤Vþp/ù;E¥ñçp5ß]iÎ¦<Ü¸þGÆ
oÑHr¹plü­¦µâIxBÄ²¾!.`áÄ7;ÚJx   ­<9u2 VPÖ!áw÷8&ûfãþQN
ÖÂ1§:Z3\¾éáZ)bû¨Pý]ñ¤oDOÕÍQd»kCâÞéøNÚ¥³£cálÀdÉcÆæ,ÂI((ppXpÒ#####
0y0Y09Ð9Ð9PÎ '=¢1¢1"0"0B1B"
BÂIHH00pÒ#
#
##!sÀ1sÀ1sÀ;7
|O÷ÇSAeç.áAàt=äHË:(#/ó²ìüÏßÔÂii10jrcLbÌ9±Òäl¨¡á±f@@ÈÑÂ"0b6#Â LFA,H0q 34â@g(Cûø)"¢3!D`DZÐQ"MpHÀ6 ,Cô!!*C(B8F8âgpÄÏ8àÞq`¹
ÂÑë&º-ÆÂ¨É111ç0Ä2H³"¢2"cÄ¸!!#1a3"âÁd4ÄÉHÐq :ã@#tÆ2!LÆcgB$Bt0H!j@¤ÉáÂ2D°"¢2"c#xÆGð8à1íK?ô?a
a}ÄO§cc)â'e >âÇ3!!#)âÇc!!:CBFbÂfDÄÉh0     &ã@#tÆFèñãqíâDÎñ#B3D
```

I don't think I need to post too much about the reporting service since that does not appear to be the issue. Here is the Post from that side, though:

```
[AddHeader(ContentType = "application/pdf")]
public object Post(ClaimInformationFormRequest request)
{
    var report = new ClaimInformationForm(request);
    return report.GetReport();
}
```

And on the app service side, things aren't much different:

```
[AddHeader(ContentType = "application/pdf")]
public object Any(ClaimInformationFormReportRequest req)
{
    //Omitted from this sample... it's BLL that creates the 'messageData' and other params/vars; works fine

    var res = new { SponsorId = paramSponsorId, ClaimMonth = paramMonth, ClaimYear = paramYear, Data = messageData };

    var client2 = ServiceClientFactory.GetJsonClient(ExternalServicesHelper.GetReportsUrl());
    client2.UseBasicAuth(UserSessionState.GetBasicAuthHeader());

    return client2.Post<byte[]>("/homes/ClaimProcessing/ClaimInformationForm", res);
}
```

I have tried a wide variety of streams, byte readings, etc. I've set up my code like many search result samples to no avail, though I have yet to find an example of passing a file between two different services. I'm sure I am missing something on the pass-through between the services, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The Content looks like a binary PDF file. You can use fiddler to call each Service so you can compare the differences between the raw HTTP Headers of both Services.

Comment: I did the above recommendation and noticed a few differences in the headers; namely the app service had a Client Accept of application-json instead of any (*/*) and the Accept-Encoding was only gzip, deflate instead of gzip, deflate, br.

I updated the client on the app service so that the Request Headers matched the reporting service. The Response body information in Fiddler for both direct calls match exactly. However, the app service is still only returning the jumbled text instead of giving a file download/save dialog like the reporting service does.

Comment: To get the download prompt you would normally need to set the Content-Disposition Header. Please update your question with the raw Response Headers for each service.

Comment: You're right mythz, I was totally missing that the application service was returning a Content-Type application/octet-stream. I changed the app service to return the byte[] as a new HttpResult(result, "application/pdf") and BINGO, we got the file download.

Answer (score 2):

After looking over the Fiddler captures as Mythz suggested and getting the headers all lined up, I realized that the application service was returning a Content-Type of application/octet-stream. The solution for this was to change the way I return the information from the application service.

Changed this:

```
return client2.Post<byte[]>("/homes/ClaimProcessing/ClaimInformationForm", res);
```

To this:

```
var result = client2.Post<byte[]>("/homes/ClaimProcessing/ClaimInformationForm", res);
return new HttpResult(result, "application/pdf");
```

I then received the file save dialog and the subsequent PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The text.txt can also be a stream

```
var result = new HttpResult("text.txt", "application/pdf");
result.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;text.txt;");
```